# SQL How to insert null value

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, null

I want to insert data into one table from another table.  In some of the columns I don't have data, so I want to set column to null.  I don't know how I should do this?

This is the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO _21Appoint(
   PCUCODE,PID,SEQ,
   DATE_SERV,APDATE,
   APTYPE,APDIAG,D_UPDATE,CID
) SELECT (
   NULL,NULL,NULL,
   treatment_date,appointment_date,
   typeap_id,appointment_id,NULL,patient_id
) FROM cmu_treatment,cmu_appointment
  WHERE cmu_treatment.treatment_id LIKE cmu_appointment.treatment_id;
```

Comment: Always include the error message you get!

Answer (score 2):

Your insert is essentially correct. Just don't put the column list in parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO _21Appoint
  (PCUCODE,PID,SEQ,DATE_SERV,APDATE,APTYPE,APDIAG,D_UPDATE,CID)
SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,treatment_date,appointment_date,typeap_id,appointment_id,NULL,patient_id
FROM cmu_treatment,cmu_appointment
WHERE cmu_treatment.treatment_id LIKE cmu_appointment.treatment_id;
```

In Postgres (unlike other DBMS) putting a column list in parentheses makes the result a single "record", rather then individual columns. And therefore the select only returns a *single* column, not multiples and thus it doesn't match the column list for the `insert`

another option is to simply leave out the columns completely:

```
INSERT INTO _21Appoint
  (DATE_SERV,APDATE,APTYPE,APDIAG,CID)
SELECT treatment_date,appointment_date,typeap_id,appointment_id,patient_id
FROM cmu_treatment,cmu_appointment
WHERE cmu_treatment.treatment_id LIKE cmu_appointment.treatment_id;
```